# How do I iterate over a JsonObject with foreach in C#

Tags: c#, json, foreach, iteration

I'm trying to foreach through a JsonObject, but unfortunately it gives me an error on the "in productSizes"

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'JsonNode' because 'JsonNode' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
var productSizes = siteJson["api"]["productDetails"]["getDetails"]["data"]["sizes"];

foreach (var size in productSizes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(size);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a cast to JsonArray which implements IEnumerable<System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode>. Casting to JsonArray should allow you to iterate against it - better yet to use pattern matching to safely check if productSizes is an instance of JsonArray first

Comment: Thank you. that fixed it. --> foreach (var size in productSizes.AsArray())

Comment: You have to post your json at least. How do we know what are you trying to get?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the AsArray() method, that's a good solution but it will throw an exception if productSizes ever comes in as something other than an array so I'd still recommend the pattern matching approach. I will put this in an answer.

Comment: To get the best possible answer include a sample of what the JSON data looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found in your comment, JsonNode has a `.AsArray()` method which [internally uses pattern matching](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c52bd824c00e87adb8490c3e69231a755c55f31b/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonNode.cs#L51-L59) to return a JsonArray. This isn't super safe, however, since it will throw an exception if `productSizes` isn't deserialized as a JsonArray.

For better safety, you are probably better off either using a try-catch or implementing the pattern matching yourself, like in the following:

```cs
if (productSizes is JsonArray jArray)
{
    foreach (var size in jArray)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(size);
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: productSizes is not an array!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `productSizes` is a `JsonArray` and iterate it:

```cs
if (productSizes is JsonArray jArr)
{
    foreach (var node in jArr)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Read more:

1. [Type-testing operators and cast expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)
2. [JSON DOM choices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#json-dom-choices)